# Return value from if condition

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I want to retrieve value from if statement of data not a null. At some point the data will be null so with my code it will return the initialize of string. How I want to retrieve the value from if condition that be null

```
String stringCheck() {
    var checkStatus;
    if (truckState.reported != null) {
      var devStatus = truckState.reported?.data?.status;
      checkStatus = devStatus;
      return checkStatus;
    }
    return checkStatus;
  }
```

I tried this somehow `checkStatus` still return null but I need data that hold inside if condition

Comment: could you remove the return statement from the if -statement and test?

Comment: Hi thanks for the replied @Georgina, if I remove return and make the function nullable, it will not return any value/data instead will stay null as per variable attribute

Answer (score 1):

In order to return nullable data, you need to change return data type to  nullable `String? stringCheck()`.

You can simply do

```dart
String? stringCheck() {
  if (truckState.reported != null) {
    String? devStatus = truckState.reported?.data?.status;
    return devStatus;
  }
}
```

Or just do

```dart
String? stringCheck()=>truckState.reported?.data?.status;
```

More about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: This is still possible to get an exception in that example, as the `data` attribute can be null even if the `truckState.reported` is not. Also, it's better to use an exclamation mark instead of a question mark after the `truckState.reported`, as it can not be null in these conditions.

Comment: In fact, you might not need a mark at all, as Dart can infer that the `truckState.reported` can not be null inside of this condition statement.

Comment: @DmytroPopov Hi, thank you for the answer. yeah true is it possible to have `data` attribute to have the return inside the `if condition` or maybe I need to do something like storing in list or anything

Comment: If you want to return the `data` attribute from a function with a non-nullable return type, you can set a default value to return from the function. For example, it can be done with `??` operator: `return truckState.reported?.data?.status ?? 'default'`. However, I must have mistyped at my comment - with nullable return type you will never get an exception when returning null, so you can freely use the sample code from the answer above. It would be better if you use the second example from the answer, as it is closer to what `Effective Dart` offers to use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'd found the solution whenever the data is not equal to null I will store the the data fetched into get storage then whenever data is null it will return the storage read.